# How to draw a background image into a 'pie' of chart js

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

`

```
var images = [
  new Image(),
  new Image(),
  new Image(),
  new Image(),
  new Image(),
  new Image()
];
//Set the source of each image
images[0].src = 'images/img1.png';
images[1].src = 'images/img2.jpg';
images[2].src = 'images/img3.jpg';
images[3].src = 'images/img4.jpg';
images[4].src = 'images/img5.jpg';
images[5].src = 'images/img6.jpg';
//Create chart
let myChart = new Chart(wheel, {
  //Plugin for displaying text on pie chart
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
  //Chart Type Pie
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    //Labels(values which are to be displayed on chart)
    labels: [`Tarde de\npaseo`, "Noche de\ncine", "Día de\npicnic", "Parrillada\n en la\nmontaña", "Tour de\nfiesta", "Paseo de\nplaya"],
    //Settings for dataset/pie
    datasets: [
      {
        //backgroundColor: pieColors,
        data: data,
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    //Responsive chart
    responsive: true,
    animation: { duration: 0 },
    plugins: {
      //Draw a background image for each piece
      drawBackgroundImages: {
        beforeDraw: (chart) => {
          const ctx = chart.ctx;
          const chartArea = chart.chartArea;
          const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
          const radius = meta.controller._radius;
          const centerX = (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2;
          const centerY = (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom) / 2;

          meta.data.forEach((element, index) => {
        const startAngle = element._model.startAngle;
        const endAngle = element._model.endAngle;
        const midAngle = startAngle + (endAngle - startAngle) / 2;

        const x = centerX + Math.cos(midAngle) * radius / 2;
        const y = centerY + Math.sin(midAngle) * radius / 2;

        ctx.drawImage(images[index], x - radius / 4, y - radius / 4, radius / 2, radius / 2);
          });
        }
      },
```

i test use the method onload() to see if the images are loading and they are. Also try with diferent images types as png and jpg. The funcionality of the code is complete except this. Any suggestion i will apreciate The project is a sping wheel
[image]